# Monotouch SIGABRT error

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, sigabrt

When launching my app in Monotouch for iOS it just crashes.

The wierd thing is that it has just been working, and with only a minor change it did drop me a SIGABRT error.. Even when trying to run with after doing a redo, it gives the same. I tried to clean code and rebuild.

Here's the complete Application Output:

```
Starting iOS simulator 6.0
Launching application
Application launched. PID = 16751
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/Emil/Projects/Lectio2/Lectio2/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/Lectio2.exe
Thread started: 
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/MonoTouch.Dialog-1.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/Emil/Downloads/FlyoutNavigation-master/FlyoutNavigation/bin/Debug/FlyoutNavigation.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/Mono.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Json.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Web.Services.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll [External]

Unhandled Exception:
0   Lectio2                             0x0008fa0e mono_handle_exception_internal_first_pass + 2190
1   Lectio2                             0x00091452 mono_handle_exception_internal + 1602
2   Lectio2                             0x00091f9f mono_handle_exception + 47
3   Lectio2                             0x000d50f2 mono_x86_throw_exception + 306
4   ???                                 0x0b496f8f 0x0 + 189362063
at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:545
at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo,object[]) [0x00174] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:299
at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type,object[],object[]) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:234
at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type,object[]) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:229
at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ConstructNSObject (intptr,intptr) [0x0000d] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:230
at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject (intptr) [0x0001f] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:279
at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObjectWrapped (intptr) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:296
at (wrapper native-to-managed) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObjectWrapped (intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00094>
13  Lectio2                             0x0020a3a3 get_managed_object_for_ptr + 115
14  Lectio2                             0x0020f230 monotouch_trampoline + 448
15  Foundation                          0x0198ae8e _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 82
16  Foundation                          0x0198a9b7 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
17  Foundation                          0x019b5428 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
18  UIKit                               0x029420cc -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
19  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x04031663 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
20  CoreFoundation                      0x0133d45a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
21  UIKit                               0x02940bcf -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1327
22  UIKit                               0x02805e37 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
23  UIKit                               0x02806418 -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
24  UIKit                               0x02806648 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 73
25  UIKit                               0x02806882 -[UIViewController view] + 33
26  UIKit                               0x02806b2a -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 36
27  UIKit                               0x0281def5 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 36
28  UIKit                               0x0281dfdb -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
29  UIKit                               0x0281e286 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 254
30  UIKit                               0x0281e381 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 72
31  UIKit                               0x0281eeab -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 386
32  UIKit                               0x0281efc9 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 41
33  UIKit                               0x0281c225 -[UINavigationController defaultFirstResponder] + 156
34  UIKit                               0x02834082 -[UIResponder(Internal) _deepestDefaultFirstResponder] + 36
35  UIKit                               0x0283409e -[UIResponder(Internal) _deepestDefaultFirstResponder] + 64
36  UIKit                               0x0283413a -[UIResponder(Internal) _promoteDeepestDefaultFirstResponder] + 36
37  UIKit                               0x0275ef14 -[UIWindow _makeKeyWindowIgnoringOldKeyWindow:] + 363
38  UIKit                               0x0275eda4 -[UIWindow makeKeyWindow] + 41
39  UIKit                               0x0275ef81 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 91
40  UIKit                               0x02722fcc -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1797
41  UIKit                               0x02723fab -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 805
42  UIKit                               0x02735315 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1022
43  UIKit                               0x0273624b -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
44  UIKit                               0x02727cf8 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
45  GraphicsServices                    0x04d10df9 _PurpleEventCallback + 339
46  GraphicsServices                    0x04d10ad0 PurpleEventCallback + 46
47  CoreFoundation                      0x012b7bf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
48  CoreFoundation                      0x012b7962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
49  CoreFoundation                      0x012e8bb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
50  CoreFoundation                      0x012e7f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
51  CoreFoundation                      0x012e7e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
52  UIKit                               0x027237da -[UIApplication _run] + 774
53  UIKit                               0x0272565c UIApplicationMain + 1211
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00056, 0x001f5>
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
at Lectio2.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/Emil/Projects/Lectio2/Lectio2/Main.cs:17
at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00049, 0x0012e>
58  Lectio2                             0x0000a762 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
59  Lectio2                             0x0016d2ee mono_runtime_invoke + 126
60  Lectio2                             0x001714e4 mono_runtime_exec_main + 420
61  Lectio2                             0x001768d5 mono_runtime_run_main + 725
62  Lectio2                             0x00067c45 mono_jit_exec + 149
63  Lectio2                             0x00205195 main + 2005
64  Lectio2                             0x00003795 start + 53
65  ???                                 0x00000004 0x0 + 4

2013-03-19 14:26:20.191 Lectio2[16751:c07] Unhandled managed exception: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0011f] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:536 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:545 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00174] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:299 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:234 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:229 
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ConstructNSObject (IntPtr ptr, IntPtr klass) [0x0000d] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:230 
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject (IntPtr ptr) [0x0001f] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:279 
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObjectWrapped (IntPtr ptr) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:296 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime:GetNSObjectWrapped (intptr)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38 
  at Lectio2.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/Emil/Projects/Lectio2/Lectio2/Main.cs:17 
Stacktrace:


Native stacktrace:

    0   Lectio2                             0x000922cc mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
    1   Lectio2                             0x000d84dd sigabrt_signal_handler + 109
    2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x95ad786b _sigtramp + 43
    3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
    4   libsystem_sim_c.dylib               0x041e157b abort + 140
    5   Lectio2                             0x00216e2b monotouch_unhandled_exception_handler + 283
    6   Lectio2                             0x0008dd3c mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 140
    7   Lectio2                             0x00091e4a mono_handle_exception_internal + 4154
    8   Lectio2                             0x00091f9f mono_handle_exception + 47
    9   Lectio2                             0x000d50f2 mono_x86_throw_exception + 306
    10  ???                                 0x0b496f8f 0x0 + 189362063
    11  ???                                 0x0e91b66c 0x0 + 244430444
    12  ???                                 0x0e91ac54 0x0 + 244427860
    13  ???                                 0x0e91a56c 0x0 + 244426092
    14  ???                                 0x0e91a4f0 0x0 + 244425968
    15  ???                                 0x0e91a2d8 0x0 + 244425432
    16  ???                                 0x0e91a1bc 0x0 + 244425148
    17  ???                                 0x0e91a0c4 0x0 + 244424900
    18  ???                                 0x0b4ba374 0x0 + 189506420
    19  Lectio2                             0x0020a3a3 get_managed_object_for_ptr + 115
    20  Lectio2                             0x0020f230 monotouch_trampoline + 448
    21  Foundation                          0x0198ae8e _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 82
    22  Foundation                          0x0198a9b7 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    23  Foundation                          0x019b5428 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
    24  UIKit                               0x029420cc -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
    25  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x04031663 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0133d45a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
    27  UIKit                               0x02940bcf -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1327
    28  UIKit                               0x02805e37 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
    29  UIKit                               0x02806418 -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    30  UIKit                               0x02806648 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 73
    31  UIKit                               0x02806882 -[UIViewController view] + 33
    32  UIKit                               0x02806b2a -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 36
    33  UIKit                               0x0281def5 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 36
    34  UIKit                               0x0281dfdb -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
    35  UIKit                               0x0281e286 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 254
    36  UIKit                               0x0281e381 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 72
    37  UIKit                               0x0281eeab -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 386
    38  UIKit                               0x0281efc9 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 41
    39  UIKit                               0x0281c225 -[UINavigationController defaultFirstResponder] + 156
    40  UIKit                               0x02834082 -[UIResponder(Internal) _deepestDefaultFirstResponder] + 36
    41  UIKit                               0x0283409e -[UIResponder(Internal) _deepestDefaultFirstResponder] + 64
    42  UIKit                               0x0283413a -[UIResponder(Internal) _promoteDeepestDefaultFirstResponder] + 36
    43  UIKit                               0x0275ef14 -[UIWindow _makeKeyWindowIgnoringOldKeyWindow:] + 363
    44  UIKit                               0x0275eda4 -[UIWindow makeKeyWindow] + 41
    45  UIKit                               0x0275ef81 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 91
    46  UIKit                               0x02722fcc -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1797
    47  UIKit                               0x02723fab -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 805
    48  UIKit                               0x02735315 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1022
    49  UIKit                               0x0273624b -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    50  UIKit                               0x02727cf8 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
    51  GraphicsServices                    0x04d10df9 _PurpleEventCallback + 339
    52  GraphicsServices                    0x04d10ad0 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    53  CoreFoundation                      0x012b7bf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    54  CoreFoundation                      0x012b7962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    55  CoreFoundation                      0x012e8bb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
    56  CoreFoundation                      0x012e7f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    57  CoreFoundation                      0x012e7e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    58  UIKit                               0x027237da -[UIApplication _run] + 774
    59  UIKit                               0x0272565c UIApplicationMain + 1211
    60  ???                                 0x0e917f75 0x0 + 244416373
    61  ???                                 0x0e914bc8 0x0 + 244403144
    62  ???                                 0x0e913f38 0x0 + 244399928
    63  ???                                 0x0e91408e 0x0 + 244400270
    64  Lectio2                             0x0000a762 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
    65  Lectio2                             0x0016d2ee mono_runtime_invoke + 126
    66  Lectio2                             0x001714e4 mono_runtime_exec_main + 420
    67  Lectio2                             0x001768d5 mono_runtime_run_main + 725
    68  Lectio2                             0x00067c45 mono_jit_exec + 149
    69  Lectio2                             0x00205195 main + 2005
    70  Lectio2                             0x00003795 start + 53
    71  ???                                 0x00000004 0x0 + 4

=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Comment: So you are saying that the code worked, you changed it and it failed, you changed it back and then it still doesn't work? I have had this problem too once, and for me it was solved by simply closing and re-starting the simulator again. You could also try removing the app within the simulator before deploying, or perhaps even test it on a physical device.

Comment: That didn't work I'm afraid :(

Comment: Please show the content of your Main.cs and mark line 17.

Comment: It's very uncommon but you could have a bad, corrupted, stale file in the simulator. By design the simulator only add files (it does not remove them) so this can lead to some weirdness. From the **iOS Simulator** menu you can select **Reset Content and Settings**. That will totally clear your simulator from **all** apps and data.

Comment: Daniel, main.cs: http://pastebin.com/CCdchuQs

Comment: @EmilElkjærNielsen: Can you add a try/catch around the Main method in your main.cs, and print out the exception you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed.. It was the method used for reading/writing txt files :)
Thanks for your help anyways!